# Backup to external HDD with terminal commands

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, terminal, backup

Is there any terminal command that allows me to backup all my files to an external HDD. My OSX update failed so I need to backup my files some how, ASAP!

Answer (score 11):

I would go with `rsync` as it only copies files changed since the last time you ran it, making it quicker on second and subsequent backups.

Assuming your username is `Freddy Frog` and your external HDD is called `My External Drive`, you could do this:

```
rsync -av "/Users/Freddy Frog" "/Volumes/My External Drive"
```

Answer (score 4):

cp -R /Path-to-folder /Path-to-external-HDD

This wil copy the folder from (Path-to-folder) to the external HDD

If you want to make this an recurring command, the are a few steps to be made:

- Open texteditor and write:

http://pastebin.com/fNuCMMr4

- Save it as Backup.plist
- Now navigate to /Library/LaunchDaemons and place the file in the folder
- Restart your machine

Every day at 15:00 the folder of /Path-to-folder will be copied to the external HDD (if the mac is running at that time)

And yes, ofcourse you need to modify the code I gave you for the .plist file

Comment: How would you modify this plist to copy more than one directory location?

Answer (score 3):

backup to a single (optionally compressed) disk image file that can be restored using Apple’s Disk Utility software with [hdiutil](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html)

```
sudo hdiutil create dst_image.dmg -format UDZO -nocrossdev -srcdir src_directory
```

OSXDaily also [provided examples](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/19/command-line-back-ups-in-os-x/) in 2009: for [ditto](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html), [rsync](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html), & [asr](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/asr.8.html)

```
sudo ditto -X src_directory dst_directory

sudo rsync -xrlptgoEv --progress --delete src_directory dst_directory

sudo asr -source src_directory -target dst_directory -erase -noprompt
```

Answer (score 0):

With new macs which use AFS (Apple file system), do:

```
diskutil list
```

to get a list of disks and their identifiers. Then, unlock your disk with:

```
diskutil apfs unlock <disk_identifier>
```

and provide your password. You should now view your disk under `/Volumes/`. For me, the disk of interest was `Macintosh HD - Data`.